# Send Mediator with VFS error WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2

I create a proxy and sequence to read file from source folder then write it to target folder with send mediator with VFS. My Proxy look like this :

```
  <proxy name="XXX" transports="vfs" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
  <description/>
  <target>
     <inSequence>
        <property name="filename"
                  expression="fn:concat(get-property('transport', 'FILE_NAME'), '')"/>
        <sequence key="write"/>
        <log level="custom">
           <property name="finish" value="finish"/>
        </log>
     </inSequence>
  </target>
  <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">1</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">file:///after</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">file:///process</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*.txt</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>
```

and my "write" sequence look like this :

```
  <sequence name="write">
  <property name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName"
            expression="get-property('filename')"
            scope="transport"/>
  <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
  <send>
     <endpoint name="FileEpr">
        <address uri="vfs:file:///Target"/>
     </endpoint>
  </send>
```

When I tried this proxy and sequence, the send mediator success to create a file in the "target" folder, but the problem is the content of the file is not written. So the size is 0 byte. My original file is 1000bytes. If I add this config in the sequence

```
      <log level="full"/>
```

it works perfectly fine. My question is, do I need to use the log full config? but when I look at the File Processing sample in WSO2 web it doesn't use any log full config. So how can I use send mediator to write file without using any "log" property?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you see any error stack in server logs?(You do not need to use log mediator in your sequence.)

Comment: @Ratha Hi ratha, nope I am not seing any error stack in the server log.

Comment: Which version of ESB you are using? Can you check with ESB 4.7.0 or later versions..We faced an similar issue in ESB 4.6.0..

Comment: @Ratha Hi ratha, sorry for the late reply, I use 4.5.0 version. So is it some kind of bug or something else? Is there any other solution to do this?